# How to compute the solution of a differential equation involving Brownian local time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-analysis

My problem is to compute numerically a function F.

F is known to be convex and have kinks. It's also known to satisfy a "second order differential equation". Since the function is not everywhere differentiable, the differential equation involves Brownian local time (as defined for example in Karantzas and Shreve 1988).

My question is, can I use standard finite difference methods to compute the solution of this differential equation? All finite differences are well defined, by I don't know if the method converges to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I got from a Professor at College de France

"Indeed, under very general conditions, the value function, if it is continuous, is the unique solution of the HJB equation in viscosity sense and finite difference methods do converge provided the scheme is monotone i.e. is order preserving."